# How to use aggregate functions in Pandas with missing values

Tags: python, pandas

---

I am a newbie to pandas and experimenting with Titanic dataset. After using groupby function, if i apply `mean()`, then it works properly. But when I calculate `std()`, I am getting `NaN`. I understood that mean by default excludes the missing values and does not consider them but std takes them into consideration.

I have tried changing `ddof=1` and `skipna=True` but they don't work with groupby. Please help. The title in my code is derived from the name using feature engineering. I am trying to predict missing value of age based on the mean and std of all the passengers age in the specified group(Like masters will have a less mean age. So missing age of a master will be calculated on mean and std of only the masters by groupby function)

```py
std = train_df.groupby(['Title'])['Age'].std()
print(std)

mean = train_df.groupby(['Title'])['Age'].mean()
print(mean)
```

```
Output for sd
Title
 Capt                  NaN
 Col              2.828427
 Don                   NaN
 Dr              19.295941
 Jonkheer              NaN
 Lady                  NaN
 Major            4.949747
 Master           3.792621
 Miss            14.525089
 Mlle             0.000000
 Mme                   NaN
 Mr              17.604569
 Mrs             16.292678
 Ms                    NaN
 Rev             13.136463
 Sir                   NaN
 the Countess          NaN


Output for mean
Title
 Capt            70.000000
 Col             58.000000
 Don             40.000000
 Dr              36.000000
 Jonkheer        38.000000
 Lady            48.000000
 Major           48.500000
 Master           4.025000
 Miss            17.450549
 Mlle            24.000000
 Mme             24.000000
 Mr              24.903288
 Mrs             31.016000
 Ms              28.000000
 Rev             43.166667
 Sir             49.000000
 the Countess    33.000000


DATAFRAME
   Survived  Pclass                                               Name     Sex  Age  SibSp  Parch            Ticket     Fare Embarked  Title
0         0       3                            Braund, Mr. Owen Harris    male   22      1      0         A/5 21171   7.2500        S     Mr
1         1       1  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...  female   38      1      0          PC 17599  71.2833        C    Mrs
2         1       3                             Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  female   26      0      0  STON/O2. 3101282   7.9250        S   Miss
3         1       1       Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)  female   35      1      0            113803  53.1000        S    Mrs
4         0       3                           Allen, Mr. William Henry    male   35      0      0            373450   8.0500        S     Mr
```

Comment: why is your question title related to R but the tags are for python? also, provide sample data so we can provide better responses instead of guessing. Finally, there's a bug with `groupby` + `std`, try to use `.apply(lambda x: x.std())`

Comment: Also, `std` might give you `nan` if your group has only one sample.

Answer (score 0):

The standard deviation is calculated as  `sqrt(sum((x-x.mean())**2)/(n-ddof))` where `n` is the length of the series and `ddof` is the Means Delta Degrees of Freedom. From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html):

> In standard statistical practice, ddof=1 provides an unbiased
>   estimator of the variance of the infinite population. ddof=0 provides
>   a maximum likelihood estimate of the variance for normally distributed
>   variables.

Please note that the **default value** for `ddof` is **`1`** in **pandas** but **`0`** in **numpy**. With a ddof of 1 we get NaN for groups with just one entry due to division by zero:

```
df.groupby(['Title'])['Age'].agg(['count','std'])
               count        std
Title                          
 Capt              1        NaN
 Col               2   2.828427
 Don               1        NaN
 Dr                6  12.016655
 Jonkheer          1        NaN
 Lady              1        NaN
 Major             2   4.949747
 Master           36   3.619872
 Miss            146  12.990292
 Mlle              2   0.000000
 Mme               1        NaN
 Mr              398  12.708793
 Mrs             108  11.433628
 Ms                1        NaN
 Rev               6  13.136463
 Sir               1        NaN
 the Countess      1        NaN
```

If you want `std` with `ddof` of `0`, you can either specify `ddof=0` for the pandas function or use the numpy function with its `ddof` default value `0`:

```
df.groupby(['Title'])['Age'].std(ddof=0)
df.groupby(['Title'])['Age'].agg(lambda x: pd.np.std(x))
```